# Visualize time-series arrays belonging to same cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, k-means

I am doing K-Means analysis on time series (hourly values), where I have divided the time-series into 24 hour windows. 
Input to K-Means looks like this:

```
[array([ 65.,  94.,  98.,  51.,  94., 100., 102.,  83.,  35.]),
 array([ 62., 100.,  99.,  70.,  88.,  46.,  59.,  44.,  18.]),
 array([62., 94., 91., 53., 85., 89., 74., 66., 22.]),
 array([ 61., 102., 106.,  64., 110., 117., 109., 102.,  47.]),
 array([ 66.,  96., 124.,  79., 101., 105., 114.,  95.,  56.]),
 array([ 55.,  75.,  82.,  47.,  89.,  93., 106.,  69.,  35.]),
```

After running K-Means I get as the output the cluster indices for each of the input arrays, like this:

```
array([[1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],])
```

Now I want to filter input arrays by the output cluster index, so that I can produce a plot with all the input arrays (1 day of values) belonging to same cluster, like this:

[image]

But I am having a trouble how to select input arrays by the cluster and then make a plot? Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you wanted to do but try this :

note : I have cut the filtering array since you didn't gave all data

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.array([ 65.,  94.,  98.,  51.,  94., 100., 102.,  83.,  35.]),
np.array([ 62., 100.,  99.,  70.,  88.,  46.,  59.,  44.,  18.]),
np.array([62., 94., 91., 53., 85., 89., 74., 66., 22.]),
np.array([ 61., 102., 106.,  64., 110., 117., 109., 102.,  47.]),
np.array([ 66.,  96., 124.,  79., 101., 105., 114.,  95.,  56.]),
np.array([ 55.,  75.,  82.,  47.,  89.,  93., 106.,  69.,  35.])]


data_to_show = []
filter = np.array([[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0]])

for idx, val in enumerate(filter):
  if val:
    data_to_show.append(data[idx])

for myArray in data_to_show: 
  print(myArray) 
  plt.plot(myArray)
```

Comment: Then i get one plot, but I want to have a different plot for every cluster.

Comment: You want different figures with one plot on each figure or you want several plots on the same figure ? because my solution gave you the second case

Comment: I want to have a new plot for every cluster (from 0 to n) and then on that plot all the days that belong to that cluster. I hope this is more clear now